# I want to check if a value in the previous column matches new value excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an Excel VBA that opens a userform and allows the user to select their name from a combo box, which week of F1 races they are betting on, and select 5 drivers and 1 manufacturer from combo boxes to bet on. This data will be input into a table where each player has 6 rows (for each driver/manufacturer) and 22 columns for weeks. So I created an elseif statement that checks the name of the player and inputs their selection into the appropriate week.

```
If UserForm1.Player = "Perry Bell" Then
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Players and Picks").Range("a3")
.Offset(1, Week) = UserForm1.Driver1
.Offset(2, Week) = UserForm1.Driver2
.Offset(3, Week) = UserForm1.Driver3
.Offset(4, Week) = UserForm1.Driver4
.Offset(5, Week) = UserForm1.Driver5
.Offset(6, Week) = UserForm1.Manufacturer
End With
ElseIf UserForm1.Player = "Christina Orchow" Then ...etc
```

What I need to do now is create a way to ensure that no one can  pick the same driver/manufacturer 2 weeks in a row. I was going to put a nested loop inside of the if statement so that after they input the data it will check row by row for duplicate choices. However this way is far too complex. I wanted to use the find method but I'm having trouble understanding the syntax. Is it possible to offset the range to search in so it will always look at the columns in the previous week?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would just a conditional formatting suffice?  That would be pretty easy to setup

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: You could setup a conditional formatting rule that if the previous entry is the same, it alters the format of that cell.  I like to do the background color for such situations.  It would not prevent the data entry, but it would alert the user to the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, find is what you want to use. You can select the column range that you need and then do the .Find off of that. Try referring to this link for the syntax:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx

Ultimately, using a single find method is fairly simple if you are searching for just one existence of your record. It gets more tricky if you need to use the .findnext to find multiple instances of the same value (mainly because you have to set a stopping point to prevent an infinite loop).

For a single search (assuming your column is C):

```
Dim Cell as Range
Dim targ as String

targ = "What I'm looking for"

Set Cell = oWksht.Range("C:C").Find(What:=targ, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
SearchFormat:=False)

If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
'Here you can do whatever you need to do when you find a value
End If
```

To reference a varying column it'll get a little more complicated but you can set your range off of a variable using Cells (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273%28v=office.15%29.aspx) which works off of number values for both columns and rows. This however forces you to track the beginning and end of your row values (which is annoying). Alternatively, I'm pretty sure there is a way to offset a Range.Column but I would have to play around with it to be sure.

**--Edit--**

This is some code I wrote last week to help with a similar problem that you mentioned in your comment below. This does a lot of extra work so you'll have to tweak it for your purposes but generally it should do what you want.

It loops through one sheet called list that has around 80 values that I needed to find in the sheet called code, then it searches the code sheet for matching values and wherever it finds a match it pastes that detail into a third sheet called Results.

Everything that you are trying to do with the exception of the variable week column should be in here.

```
Sub Search_Select()

Dim oWkbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim oWksht As Excel.Worksheet   'Code Sheet
Dim oRsht As Excel.Worksheet    'Results Sheet
Dim oLsht As Excel.Worksheet    'List Sheet
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Cell2 As Range
Dim firstaddress As String
Dim targ As String
Dim listrow As Integer
Dim pstrow As Integer
Dim found As String
Dim foundfull As String

Set oWkbk = ThisWorkbook
Set oWksht = oWkbk.Sheets("Code")
Set oLsht = oWkbk.Sheets("List")
Set oRsht = oWkbk.Sheets("Results")

pstrow = 1
oRsht.Cells.Clear 'Clear data from Results

For listrow = 2 To 79
    targ = oLsht.Cells(listrow, 2).Value                    'Search Target
    oRsht.Range("A" & pstrow).Value = oLsht.Cells(listrow, 1).Value & "." & targ                    'Column A in Results
    Set Cell = oWksht.Range("C:C").Find(What:=targ, LookAt:=xlPart,     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
        firstaddress = Cell.Address
        Do
            found = oWksht.Cells(Cell.row, 2).Value
            If Not (found = targ) Then
                foundfull = oWksht.Cells(Cell.row, 1).Value & "." & found
                oRsht.Range("B" & pstrow).Value = foundfull
                pstrow = pstrow + 1
            End If
        Set Cell = oWksht.Range("C:C").FindNext(Cell)
        Loop While Not Cell Is Nothing And Cell.Address <> firstaddress
    End If
pstrow = pstrow + 1
Next listrow

Set oWkbk = Nothing
Set oWksht = Nothing
Set oRsht = Nothing
Set oLsht = Nothing
MsgBox "Completed", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out and report back.

Comment: So the problem with this is, I have essentially 10 data points to compare (2 columns of 5 rows). So in my mind it would need to target Driver 1, Week 2 and find all instances of that string in Week 1. Then have a loop to make it target driver 2, week 2 and so on.

Comment: I'll post some code that does just that.... but you'll have to tweak it for your own purposes.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up trying a different route at first but this will greatly help my future spreadsheets.